Is there a way to have diferent build variants for Ktor project in intellij like the way we do in Adroid development?
I have a Ktor project and I am trying to achieve a setup where I can have three build variants, Dev, Sit, and Prod and load secretes to BuildConfigs for each variant so I can choose among these variants dynamically. Below I will show a working example of how I achieve this in Android Studio for an Android application and my current Ktor build.gradle.kts file:

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsCompose)
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)
    alias(libs.plugins.ksp)
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization")
}

val secretsFileDev = rootProject.file("secrets.dev.properties")
val secretsFileSit = rootProject.file("secrets.sit.properties")
val secretsFileProd = rootProject.file("secrets.properties")

val devProperties = Properties().apply {
    load(secretsFileDev.inputStream())
}
val sitProperties = Properties().apply {
    load(secretsFileSit.inputStream())
}
val prodProperties = Properties().apply {
    load(secretsFileProd.inputStream())
}

val code = 1
val name = "1.0.0"

android {
    namespace = "com.myapp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.myapp"
        manifestPlaceholders["hostName"] = prodProperties["hostName"].toString()
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = code
        versionName = name

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }

        manifestPlaceholders["hostName"] = prodProperties["hostName"].toString()
    }

    flavorDimensions.add("environment")

    productFlavors {
        create("dev") {
            dimension = "environment"
            applicationIdSuffix = ".dev"
            versionNameSuffix = "-dev"
            loadProperties(devProperties, ::buildConfigField)
        }
        create("sit") {
            dimension = "environment"
            applicationIdSuffix = ".sit"
            versionNameSuffix = "-sit"
            loadProperties(sitProperties, ::buildConfigField)
        }
        create("prod") {
            dimension = "environment"
            applicationIdSuffix = ".prod"
            versionNameSuffix = "-prod"
            loadProperties(prodProperties, ::buildConfigField)
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName("debug") {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".debug"
            isDebuggable = true
        }

        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
        buildConfig = true
        viewBinding = true
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            if (output is com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApkVariantOutputImpl) {
                if (variant.buildType.isDebuggable) {
                    output.outputFileName =
                        "myapp${variant.versionName}(${variant.versionCode}).apk"
                } else {
                    output.outputFileName = "myapp-${variant.versionName}.apk"
                }
            }
            true
        }
    }
}

/** 
* Dynamically load properties into buildConfigFields.
*/
fun loadProperties(properties: Properties, buildConfigField: (String, String, String) -> Unit) {
    buildConfigField("String", "baseUrl", properties["baseUrl"].toString())
    buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", properties["API_KEY"].toString())
    buildConfigField("String", "GCP_API_KEY", properties["GCP_API_KEY"].toString())
}

dependencies {
    /** dependencies here */
}

And now the current Ktor build.gradle.kts: How can I achieve the same for the Ktor project?  PS: I am using Intellij for this project.

val exposedVersion: String by project
val h2Version: String by project
val hikariCPVersion: String by project
val koinVersion: String by project
val kotlinVersion: String by project
val ktorVersion: String by project
val logbackVersion: String by project
val mySQLVersion: String by project

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "2.0.10"
    id("io.ktor.plugin") version "2.3.12"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "2.0.10"
}

group = "com.myktor-backend"
version = "0.0.1"

application {
    mainClass.set("com.myktor-backended.ApplicationKt")

    val isDevelopment: Boolean = project.ext.has("development")
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = listOf("-Dio.ktor.development=$isDevelopment")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    /** Dependencies */
}


Can you describe the expected behavior on the Ktor side?
